# Delete User profile older than X days globllay from all the COmputer within domian. Server 2008 R2

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I need little help for deleting all the user profile form the Computer within my domain. if user is not logged in to particular computer for Than x Day in my case 60 Days.

i have tried with default Domain policy from windows server 2008 R2 but it doesn't seems to work.

can someone please suggest any Idea , how can i achieve it?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use [Delprof2](https://helgeklein.com/free-tools/delprof2-user-profile-deletion-tool/) in a startup script or scheduled task

```
Usage: delprof2 [/l] [/u] [/q] [/p] [/r] [/c:[\\]<computername>] [/d:<days> [/ntuserini]] [/ed:<pattern>] [/id:<pattern>] [/i]

   /l   List only, do not delete (what-if mode)
   /u   Unattended (no confirmation)
   /q   Quiet (no output and no confirmation)
   /p   Prompt for confirmation before deleting each profile
   /r   Delete local caches of roaming profiles only, not local profiles
   /c   Delete on remote computer instead of local machine
   /d   Delete only profiles not used in x days
   /ntuserini
        When determining profile age for /d, use the file NTUSER.INI
        instead of NTUSER.DAT for age calculation
   /ed  Exclude profile directories whose name matches this pattern
        Wildcard characters * and ? can be used in the pattern
        May be used more than once and can be combined with /id
   /id  Include only profile directories whose name matches this pattern
        Wildcard characters * and ? can be used in the pattern
        May be used more than once and can be combined with /ed
   /i   Ignore errors, continue deleting
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @ Shaun Vermaak i have to run this script for more than 15 computers in the domain and and script should work for every computer :

Comment: I checked this tool and its on the website that it doesnt work with Operating system newer than Windows XP?

i have windows server 2008R2 and Clients are windows 7

Comment: BTW i have installed this Software within my machine but it doesnt seems to work.

Comment: You need to use Delprof2 not the original delprof. Quote from the Delprof2 website "Delprof2 has been tested on 32-bit and 64-bit versions of: Windows 8, Windows 7, Vista, XP, Server 2008 (R2), Server 2003."

Comment: I will download again but I have also tried delprof2 not the original one but when I run the .exe file of delprof2 .Then just one command shell open and then with any keyboard events its again disappear

Comment: And then next question I's do I need to buy this software?

Comment: The licensing information is on the link provided

Comment: Yes! I Have checked it and for the commercial use i need to buy this!!
what i am looking for is any Powershell Script or Any other solution!!

but anyway thanks this is really the best tool , i have tested it personally!

Comment: No you did not. What's up with all the exclamation points? Delprof2 may only be used free of charge by all other, especially commercial, organizations, if a representative authorized to do so sends an e-mail with the following text to info@helgeklein.com: “We authorize Helge Klein GmbH to publicly display the name and logo of our company FILL IN NAME HERE in Helge Klein GmbH’s marketing materials.”